# WSO2 ESB and Websocket

Tags: websocket, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

Is it possible to use WSO2 ESB as a mediator between a WebSocket client and a (Web service) server (or between a Websocket server and a Web service client)?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB currently not supports websockets. However, I think its possible to invoke a websocket server from a java code. In that case you can write a class mediator to do so.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 ESB will support WebSocket in upcoming release 4.10.
[Reference](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1999)